# Mod Url rewrite Query

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am trying to implement a url rewrite rule so that if  /upload/ appears in the Url then redirect to a different page for validation.

Example Url : https://myWebsiteUrl.com/upload/827433/kite-mark.jpg

Basically I need to Pass over everything after the first / in upload

So I need R:0 to just contain upload/827433/kite-mark.jpg as the Value.

Could someone provide some Regular expression to resolve or are there any other suggestions.

Thanks a lot

Kevin

Comment: From where does `D6538475AGS` come?

Comment: That's what the file name is . I just removed it to make a clean file name

Comment: So, what happens when a user visits `https://mywebsiteurl.com/upload/827433/kite-mark.jpg`?

Comment: It displays the image . Where as I meant it to direct to a download page. I have created

Comment: and the redirected URL would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a regex expression like this:

```
/upload(.*)/
```

Also, here is a good regex resource for learning/testing things out:
http://www.regexr.com/

If you want to limit your results to only those things ending with common image file extensions (jpg, png, gif, etc..) you could do this:

```
/upload(.*)(jpg|png|gif)/
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work in the Regex tester. I'll try it in the iis rewrite module in the morning and Mark as correct should it work .

Comment: That also seems to catch https://mywebsiteurl.com/documentupload/Doc.docx

So this will apply the redirect here as well which i want to avoid

Comment: ? None of that was in the original string you were regexing on @KevinO'Reilly

Comment: Apologies . I thought if I could get the /upload/ it would ignore the rest. I didn't realise I would pick up on any directory with the word upload in it.

Comment: @KevinO'Reilly check updated answer if you want more specific regex filtering